# Запуск скрипта на питоне из java кода

Tags: java, python

У меня есть скрипт на питоне который генерит текстовые файлы с данными
'(with open('./data_min_out.txt', 'a') as f2:)'
Я могу запустить обычный скрипт с помощью Desktop.open(filename.py) но этот вроде как запускается но файлы не создает. Как мне запустить этот скрипт?

Comment: Почему бы не генерить текстовые файлы в Java?

Answer (score 2):

В *java* существует удобный *api* для запуска процессов. Вам следует воспользоваться классом `ProcessBuilder`. Простейший пример будет выглядеть так:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder()
            .command("echo", "hello world")
            .start();

System.out.println(process.waitFor());
```

Здесь происходит запуск команды `echo`, и передача ей в качестве параметров строки `hello world`